# Jquery - Is it possible to add animation to AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation

I have some content that I am loading to my page using AJAX. When it loads it flashes on screen and looks a bit messy. Is there anyway to add some jquery animations to it???

```
$("#posts").load("posts.php", {from_user: fm}, function(){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a wrapper to load content into. Assume you have `<div class="postWrap"></div>` inside `<div id="posts"></div>`.

**CSS**

.postWrap { display: none; opacity: 0 }

**JS**

```
$("#posts .postWrap").load(
  "posts.php",
  {from_user: fm},
  function() {
    $("#post .postWrap").fadeIn(); //for example, you could use any effect
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `$.ajax()` instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'posts.php',
    data: {from_user: fm},
    success: function( html ) {
        $(html).hide().appendTo('#posts').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("posts.php", {from_user: fm}, function(html){
   $(html).hide().appendTo('yourSelector').fadeIn();
});
```

Or `$.post` or `$.ajax`... just not load because you need to hide it and then animate it in.